# find only files in directory with permissions not set to 644 on linux

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, find

This is my first question although I've been lurking for a while.

Question:
I would like to use find to get only the files in a directory with permissions not set to 644 (or another permission value).  Is there shorter way to write this or is the only way to just use the -perm and -or options and list each permission type except for 644?

This is part of a larger command that I was hoping to speed up:

```
find /path/to/dir/ -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 644
```

I'm hoping that providing xargs only the file names that need updated will speed it up.  The directory has ~ a million files but only ~10,000 usually need permissions updated.  I think the command is slow because it is still piping all the files regardless.  Maybe there is a more efficient approach to the larger command.  Let me know if you know of one.  I'd still like to know the answer to this question though.  And btw, I can't update the permissions before adding the files to the directory.

Comment: The command executes in < 2 seconds when before it took more than 5 minutes so this is a much better method although I never see examples doing it this way.  Thanks everyone.

    find /path/to/dir/ -type f ! -perm 0644 -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 644

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `!` operator returns true when a condition is false.

So while `-perm 0644` matches files that have rw-r--r-- permissions set, `! -perm 0644` matches those that don't have those permissions.

The command you need is:

```
find /path/to/dir/ -type f ! -perm 0644 -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 644
```

Comment: This works great.  The ! flag was exactly what I needed.  The query is now almost instant instead of taking ~ 5 minutes.  I now see it mentioned in the man file at the bottom.

Answer (score 3):

```
  find /path/to/dir ! -perm 0644
```

And

```
    find /path/to/dir ! -perm 0644 -exec chmod 0644 {} \;
```

Comment: /path/to/dir has to be before the !.

Comment: This works also but for whatever reason -exec is slower than piping to xargs for this since it is a large directory.  -exec might be performing individual commands instead of batching like xargs?

Comment: @M Brown, in the future, try using `+` instead of `\;`.  That will do the same kind of batching as xargs.

Answer (score 3):

At least with GNU find, you can use the ! operator for negation with -perm. For example:

```
find /path/to/dir ! -perm 644
```

Based on the example you're giving, are you just looking to ensure that the owners have at least read/write and everyone has at least read? If so, then you can just do it with chmod:

```
chmod -R a+r,u+w /path/to/dir/*
```

Comment: The ! operator is what I was missing.  I have to use find and then pipe to xargs because of the large number of files in the directory.  chmod can't handle the number of files.

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution would be if you have less directories, run a `chmod -R 644 /path/to/dir` and then run a `find /path/to/dir -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;`.

Comment: There are no directories only files.  I use xargs because of the large number of files.